# Post & Category Archives URL structure

Tags: posts, permalinks, urls

I've looked through many similar questions, but haven't yet been able to find a solution to my particular problem. It seems fairly straight-forward, but I can't seem to find the correct combination of settings to fit my desired structure. I would like my (standard) posts to have a URL of *mysite.com/blog/postname*. I then have a couple of category archives that I would like to have a URL of *mysite.com/blog/categoryname.*

In the Permalinks menu, setting a custom structure of */blog/%postname%/* generates the correct URLs for the single post view, but sets a URL of *mysite.com/blog/category/categoryname* for the archive. Using a plugin like Yoast to remove /category/ from the URL generates the correct link to the category page in the WP-provided navigation (*mysite.com/blog/categoryname*), but seems to ultimately redirect to *mysite.com/categoryname*.

I've also tried different combinations like setting *blog* in both the custom structure and the category base. This generates the correct links in WP-nav and to the category archives, but ultimately results in a 404 for the single posts.

It seems like I'm overlooking something simple, so I would appreciate it if anyone could point me in the correct direction. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The issue with your desired structure (and that categories without base are common request but commonly unreliable) is ambiguity.

Each rewrite rule is like a tiny program, explaining WP how to turn URL into query variables. It is *very* important that WP can reliably distinguish *which* of the rules should handle particular URL.

In plain words the usual case would be following rules:

1. `blog`, followed by post name.
2. `blog`, followed by taxonomy name, followed by term name.

With your configuration rules become the following:

1. `blog`, followed by post name.
2. `blog`, followed by term name.

Notice how this is **much** less clear case. How is WP supposed to guess if that is post or term at the end? How is it supposed to guess *which* taxonomy that term belongs to?

In a nutshell such structure is inherently unreliable and is not supported by WP core. You might beat it into submission eventually, but I would recommend just to stick with robust and unambiguous rewrite rules.

Comment: I really appreciate taking the time to provide this information. It makes perfect sense, and at least gives me some ammo to push back a bit.